# AzureADDefaults is obsolete

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, obsolete

I have following code for Azure AD authentication:

```
services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name, builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        });
    })
    .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options =>
    {
        configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    });

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    ...
}
```

AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme and AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme are now obsolete with message "Use Microsoft.Identity.Web instead. See [https://aka.ms/ms-identity-web."](https://aka.ms/ms-identity-web.%22). However I can't find any clear documentation how to upgrade following code to use Identity.Web instead of those obsolete constants.

Does anyone have instructions how to remove this obsolete code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [blog](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/comparing-a-net-core-application-for-the-identity-platform-and-identity-web-3c0bf5722c34) shows you the differences between `Identity Platform` and `Identity.Web`.

For Identity.Web, we use `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI`. Try to see this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg#an-aspnet-core-web-app-signing-in-users-with-the-microsoft-identity-platform-in-your-organization), and it uses *AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication* to sign in users.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
            options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
        });

        // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```